# Given the equation of the parabola, for what values of $t$ will the quadratics have $0$, $1$, or $2$ solutions?

Tags: quadratics

Given the equation of the parabola, for what values of $t$ will the quadratics have $0$, $1$, or $2$ solutions? Equation: $$0 = 3x^2 + tx + 10$$

Can you please explain the answer in simple terms, step by step if you can. How do I figure this out? I tried plugging in the $0$, $1$, and $2$ for the $x$ variables and solve for $t$ but that only gave me a correct solution for $0$ (when I plugged in $0$ $t$ had $0$ $x$ intercepts, but when I plugged in $1$ and later $2$, both had $2$ solutions so there must be something wrong there).

Comment: There is no reason to expect $x = 0,1,2$ to correspond in any way to the cases of $0,1,2$ solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The solution for your equation is $$x = -\frac{t}{6} \pm \sqrt{\frac{t^2}{36} - \frac{10}{3}}$$

The stuff below the square root sign ($\frac{t^2}{36} - \frac{10}{3}$) is the important thing. You get exactly one solution when it equals zero, two solutions when it is positive and no (real) solutions when it is negative.

Can you find out when the different cases occur? And why this is so?

Comment: So when there is one solution and it equals to zero it means there is one x-intercept at the vertex, hence 1 solution and x = 0. When there is a positive number you ± the number, hence there are two x-intercepts (2 solutions). When the number is negative you can't square root the number so there are no x-intercepts/no solutions.

Comment: @Simon Yes, that's correct! :) But for the case when there is one solution it is not neccessarily zero, it will be $x = \frac{t}{6}$, whatever $t$ is.

Comment: What I don't understand is how you got this equation... I know the quadratic equation but this seems to look different (is this a modified quadratics equation?).

Comment: @Simon I don't know which country you're from and how they teach you to solve quadratics there, but I divide each term by $3$ to get $x^2 + \frac{t}{3}x + \frac{10}{3} = 0$, and then use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Reduced_quadratic_equation

Comment: Sorry I meant the quadratics formula: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quads/qform01.gif

Comment: I'm from Canada, they taught us to use it to find the x-intercepts from the standard form.

Comment: @Simon I can't view your image. Anyway, the x-intercepts are given by the method I described. As long as you understand the method, you've learned something useful. :)

Comment: ok thanks, btw try this one: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/b/b/a/bba46479d07af61b6e596219ce4e2cd5.png

Comment: @Simon That link works. And yes, that's the same formula, but with $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$3x^2  + tx + 10 = 0$. Discriminant: $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = t^2 - 120$.

If $\Delta > 0$ two real solutions, that is, $t^2 - 120 > 0 \ \Rightarrow \ t < -2\sqrt{30}$ and $t > 2\sqrt{30}$

If  $\Delta = 0$ one real solution, that is, $t^2 - 120 = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ t =\pm 2\sqrt{30}$

If  $\Delta < 0$ no real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{R}$ an equation of the form: $$z^{2}=c$$ has $2$ solutions
if $c>0$ (then $z=\pm\sqrt{c}$), has $1$ solution if $c=0$ (then
$z=0$) and has no solutions if $c<0$.

If $a\neq0$ then the following statements are equivalent:

$$ax^{2}+bx+c=0$$

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^{2}=\frac{b^{2}-4ac}{4a^{2}}$$

Note that the last line can be written as $z^{2}=c$ for $z=x+\frac{b}{2a}$
and $c=\frac{b^{2}-4ac}{4a^{2}}$. This leads to:

If $\frac{b^{2}-4ac}{4a^{2}}>0$ or equivalently $b^{2}-4ac>0$ then
there are $2$ solutions.

If $\frac{b^{2}-4ac}{4a^{2}}=0$ or equivalently $b^{2}-4ac=0$ then
there is $1$ solution.

If $\frac{b^{2}-4ac}{4a^{2}}<0$ or equivalently $b^{2}-4ac<0$ then
there are $0$ solutions.

So crucial here is the sign of $D:=b^{2}-4ac$ (the so-called discriminant).

Apply this on your
question where $a=3$, $b=t$ and $c=10$.